# What additional privileges does an Editor and Contributor need to Cut And Paste in Contents tab?

Tags: security, workflow, plone

In Plone 4 I have made a user a Contributor and an Editor but not a Manager. I would like for this user to be able to Copy-And-Paste any Plone object in the Contents tab of the Plone Interface.

Unfortunately this user gets an "Insufficient Privileges" error when he attempts to do so. What privileges do I need to give this user so that he can cut and paste any object in the Contents tab?

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought that would be enough, but two thoughts come to mind:

1. Is he Contributor/Editor in both the context of the folder from which he's cutting *and* the folder into which he's pasting?
2. Are the objects being ***cut*** actually addable in the location where they're being pasted?

Answer (score 2):

I have recently seen this go wrong with the same Insufficient Privileges error when the user did not have the View permission (or the Reader role) on all the folders from the root of the site to the item being copied or pasted.  See http://dev.plone.org/plone/ticket/11573

Answer (score 2):

Cut+paste requires different privileges than copy+paste. You question doesn't make it clear which you require.

For copy+paste, your role assignments of Contributor + Editor for the folder being pasted into sound fine. In addition to the user needs to be able to view the content itself in addition to the folder it's in, I think.

For cut+paste, the user also needs to be able to delete items from the source folder, which may be what is causing your issue here (cut+paste is implemented as a "delete" from the source and an "add" to the destination).

As Auspex says, check the restrictions on the folder being pasted to.

You can run Plone in "verbose security" mode, which should help find the issue. See http://plone.org/documentation/kb/debug-unauthorized. You will probably require the instructions under "For Zope 2.8+".

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the permissions locally via the Sharing tab, just double check that the permissions are set for the actual container and not the default view.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped. I went to error_log and removed Insufficient Rights from the list of errors that are not logged. Then when I tried to cut and paste again the error message told me which right I needed to turn on.